# How to commit information to the server with Vue?

Tags: rest, web, vue.js

I am not well versed in javascript/web programming, so pardon me if it sounds trivial.

I am using Vue to define my frontend. I also have a server that provides a  REST interface. This REST interface provides a resource, say /users/.
When in Vue I perform an operation that adds a user, I modify the Vue ViewModel, but that is local to the browser and nothing has been persisted to the backend yet.

This last step is what I don't understand. What is the best practice and intended pattern to persist the new user to the backend with vue?

Answer (score 0):

You can send POST requests to store data on your server, and GET requests to get data from backend to your Vue app. I recommend using [vue-axios](https://github.com/imcvampire/vue-axios) for this purpose.

Comment: ok, but where does it enter in the whole Vue mechanism? Do I have to listen to the viewmodel, and when they change, perform the POST?

Comment: What I mean is. established the viewmodel, where is the proper place to perform synchronization between viewmodel and backend model?

Comment: you can listen to button click and submit data in the callback method.

Comment: @StefanoBorini promises are pretty cool stuff in Javascript and Axios.When you make request to server, you wait for promise to be resolved and when It's done, you are updating the data model of your Vue App aka front-end and everything is in the sync.
In case that promise is not resolved you simply throw error and doesn't update your app model/state.

Comment: @StefanoBorini If you're that worried about proper state management, just use Vuex. You can perform ajax requests inside an "action".

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to do it, basically you need to send an ajax request to the server when something happens, probably on button click. I'm using a cool library to help with all api things: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios

with that you can do

```
methods: {
  saveUser: function() {
    this.axios.post('/user', {
      firstName: this.firstName,
      lastName: this.lastName
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

You can read more about axios here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

and you have a nice tutorial here:

Vue Ajax Requests With Axios: 
https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/18

Comment: Ok, but isn't it kind of unexpected that I have to perform this operation from the View? This is a model operation.

Comment: Stefano, you are adding a user and updating the viewModel. There, in that action, you can peform the axios.post to save the user. there's a lot of ways and "times" to update the user, you can create it on click, you can do it on focusout on input, you can even update the user while you are typing in the input. If you want more specific help you need to ask more specific questions :)

Answer (score 0):

A state management tool like [`vuex`](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex) is helpful when you need to maintain state between the frontend and backend via RESTful calls.

Vuex maintains a `state` object and only lets you make changes to the state via special methods called mutations, which are only called by other methods called actions. Actions can be asynchronous and they are accessible to any component using the vuex store via `this.$store.dispatch('[action name]', params)`.

Using this structure, when you want to make a change in your application that should be mirrored on your backend (say, creating a user), you can put a RESTful api call in an action, and upon success, commit a change to the vuex state object.

Components can reference the vuex state via other special methods called getters. You can find the full documentation [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/).

Here's a sample vuex store:

```
new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    users: [],
  },
  mutations: {
    CREATE_USER(state, userData) {
      users.push(userData);
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async createUser({commit}, userData) {
      await yourHTTPClient.post('/users', userData)
        .then((response) => {
          commit('CREATE_USER', userData);
        }).catch((error) => {
          throw new Error(error);
        });
    },
  },
  getters: {
    users(state) {
      return state.users;
    }
  }
});
```

The vue component could call the action like so:

```
methods: {
  addUser(data) {
    this.$store.dispatch('createUser', data)
      .then((success) => {
        alert('User added!');
      }).catch((error) => {
        alert('Something went wrong...');
      });
  }
}
```